# Removing Transparency from animated GIF

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

[image]

This *admin* image that I created for my website has some funky things going on. The white of the characters hair on the left isn’t there in photoshop and the white at the end before it loops the animation isn't there in photoshop but when I save it for the web it brings all these problems out. These problems aren't in the preview.

(You can’t really tell on Stack Exchange because of the white background, but on a black background it would look really poorly designed.)

Does anyone know what I should be doing?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the issue. Here‘s the new, fixed image:

[image: fixed image]

This is the image which does not have the problem.

The problem was that my Gaussian Blur filter had a larger hitbox than the size of the black rounded background. So when the end of the animation happened it would show the Gaussian blur on a black background looking really tacky. I fixed this by changing the size of the blur.

Comment: Hey Ryan! Welcome to GD.SE! I'm confused, did you ask the question under a different user name and then answer it yourself? (the "Alright nevermind I fixed it" is confusing) Regardless, it would be helpful if you could provide a clear, step-by-step set of instructions for how you achieved the desired end result for people to follow.

Comment: Yeah I think I have two accounts somehow, the first being when i clicked the "Login with google" and the other was as a guest I think? I don't really know how to explain what I did in words. The Gaussian blur was large than the black box so I had to shrink it so it didn't go and fall out of the image creating an ugly white box for a second (can only be seen on a black background though). How do I change my name?

Comment: @RyanGlen:  Please take a look at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.